# Any way to re-enable first time login screen?

Tags: soql, test-automation

Doing some automation testing, and wondering if there is any way to re-enable the screen that shows up the first time a user logs into a sandbox asking you to register your phone number or click 'I don't want to register my phone' etc.

Is there any SOQL query you can run against an account that yields that result, and if so is it upsertable or read-only?

Any help appreciated!